# Can I access Sessionstate in web api?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a MVC application and added new WebApi controller in it called ReportsApiController. And i created a session called Session["ReportId"]=5 in application and tried to access from web Api method but it is throwing null reference exception. I am accessing the WebApi using $.getJASON method.Let me know how can i get it resolved.

Comment: Session state is not accessible from ApiControllers

Comment: @BryanRoss Ross - Any work around that i can try to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can if the Web API is hosted in the same web application that stored the value in the session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

But you should not do it. This violates the stateless nature of the Web API. If you need to pass some information to this API, don't make it depend on some session state. Pass this information under the form of a model. Or if you don't want to pass complex data, simply persist this information in some common datastore (could be a database for example) and then only pass the id to the Web API so that it retrieves the value from the datastore.

Comment: I didn't understand "hosted in same application" means. Can you please explain.

Comment: You need to host the Web API somewhere, right? It could be self hosted in a console application or host it in an existing ASP.NET application. ASp.NET Session is available only within the same application. So, if despite my recommendation against, you still decide to use sessions in your Web API application, this application code must reside in the same ASP.NET application which is storing values to this session.

Comment: That makes me clear.Anyways i will find another approach to achieve my functionality. Thanks

Comment: Using Web Api 4.5 HttpContext.Current.Session is null...Any ideas how to use Session in ASP.NET MVC Web Api 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Think out of the box, Web API is STATELESS service, so Session stuff will not suit anymore, it is not like ASP.NET web form which simulates stateful website with Session, ViewState.

Depend on your case, but you can use `MemoryCache` instead if you want to cache something.